# How to force a chosen jquery select to stay always openned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I've a simple select initialized with jQuery Chosen, created on a hidden div.

```
$(".slcFriendlist").chosen({
    no_results_text: 'Geen resultaten voor',
    width: 300
});
```

When I click somewhere in my code I show it and I would like to open the select, and mantain it opened

```
$('.pcPhotoFriend').on('click', function(event){
    $('div.pcPostcardFriendlist').show();
    $(".slcFriendlist").trigger('chosen:open');
});
```

But the problem is that there is another event that trigger I guess the click outside the select, or something else, and my select get closed again -I saw it opens, tested with delay in operations- but that's not what I need.

My goal is to have a select always opened.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried adding `event.preventDefault();` in there?

Comment: yes I did, but nothing changes, because for sure it's not that click that shows the select, I guess it should be something else.

Comment: You may need to post some more code - I just tested locally and the code you've posted works fine, so there might be something else that's affecting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved like that, with the adding of [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$('.pcPhotoFriend').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('div.pcPostcardFriendlist').show();
    $(".slcFriendlist").trigger('chosen:open');
});
```